# DatagramPacket + DatagramSocket how to use Offset?

Tags: java, networking, udp

What exactly do you use Offset for? What is it used for and how do I use it? Right now I am just sending my packets with no offset and processing them from the start. Also what are the advantages of using Offset? I'm just having a hard time understanding the uses of it since I have to parse the data anyway.

Comment: @close-voter I don't see anything unclear about this question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use it. It lets you send part of an array, or receive into the middle of an array. But if you don't have a use for it, don't worry about it.

Comment: I am just curious, can you give me an example of where an Offset would be useful. Maybe some built in Java libraries that make use of the Offset? I know I don't use it and right now I am not worried about it but I can't help but wonder when I understand the usefulness of it I will want to rewrite my network code to incorporate it.

Comment: but I need to specify which part of the array I want returned anyway when I convert the bytes to a String. Offset doesn't even automatically extract the array properly for me. Maybe I should post a sample code of what I am talking about.